# How to post a IFromFile along with other properties as a collection to .Net core 2.2 Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I want to perform bulk file upload where I have IFormFile and additional properties as a collection.

I've successfully uploaded a single object using the mentioned test cases however when I send it as an array it fails to process the request.

Below is my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> BulkUploadFilesByPath([FromForm] List<BulkUploadRequest> bulkFiles)
```

Below is the Request Object

```
public class BulkUploadRequest
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is my test case where I'm trying to make a request to the controller

```
[Fact]
        public async Task BulkUploadFileSuccess()
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            var values = new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ClientId", "Bar")
            };
            foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
            }

            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_testFileDir + "Test Document 1.pdf"));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                FileName = "Test Document 1.pdf",
                Name = "File"
            };
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

            content.Add(fileContent, "File", "Test Document 1.pdf");
            var requestUri = "/api/directories/bulkupload";

            var result = _client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;

        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2) article?

Comment: Yes @felix-b, I've gone through the document and I've successfully made a http post request for a single object however when I'm failing to make it work for a list of object.